# Example of a function $f(x)$ such that the integral of $f(x^2)$ converges but the integral of $f(x)$ diverges?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Does anybody know an example of a function $f(x)$ such that the integral from $1$ to infinity of $f(x^2)$ converges but the integral of $f(x)$ from $1$ to infinity diverges?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a series you can think of that converges for $f(n^2)$ but diverges for $f(n)$?

Comment: $\sin x$ is another, more intriguing example

Comment: @mrf, concerning the sin, it's related to the uniform continuity. :x$\rightarrow x$ is uniformly continuous while $ :x\rightarrow x^2 $ is not. One will make it converge, the other not. I've asked a question about this if you're interested :) :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003956/a-question-about-integral-and-uniformly-continuous-functions

Answer (score 11):

Take $f(x)=\frac1x$ then

$$\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$$
is divergent and 
$$\int_1^\infty f(x^2)dx$$
converges.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest example I can think of is, $f(x) = x^{-1}$, $\int_1^\infty x^{-1}dx$ diverges but $\int_1^\infty x^{-2}dx =1$

Answer (score 2):

The integral $$\int_1^{\infty} x^p \,dx$$ converges (to $\frac{1}{p + 1}$) iff $p < -1$, so the integral $f(x) := x^p$ diverges and the integral of $f(x^2) := x^{2p}$ converges iff $-1 \leq p < -\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Shouldn't the last 1/2 be negative?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the catch!